# python convert vector input function to multiinput

Tags: python, wrapper

I have a function that takes a vector input, e.g.

```
f(x) = x[0]*x[1]
```

I want a function that takes this function and creates a new function:

```
g(x,y) = x*y

fcn_translator(f)
    # intelligent code here
    return g
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Has this been done before. The reason for this question is that I have a python package that optimizes a function of the form f(x,y...) but the function that I'm calling acts on a vector.

Comment: You can call a function of the form `f(x,y,...)` with a vector like `f(*vector)`

Comment: how does that help? I don't have f(x,y,...), I have f(vector)

Comment: How do you expect `f` to be applied in `g`? `g(x, y)` is supposed to do `f(x) * f(y)`, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a function that takes two parameters, combines them into a vector, and calls `f`:

```
def g1(x, y):
    return f([x, y])
```

As a more general solution, the function `g2` takes any number of parameters, combines them into a vector, and calls `f`:

```
def g2(*x):
    return f(x)
```

Finally, since the first two elements of the vector are required for `f`, this function takes *at least two* parameters:

```
def g3(x, y, *rest):
    return f((x, y) + rest)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help DYZ. Is there a way to automatically generate a function like g3? for example, given the definition of f(x), is there code that creates g3(x1,x2,...) ?

Comment: You can create new functions with `exec('''def f_new(x, y):return f([x, y])''')`, but the use of `exec` is strongly discouraged.